# Is my Array too big, or why does I get this error?

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer, int

```
C:\javac schiffe3.java                                                               
schiffe3.java:96: error: ';' expected                                                 
String[] Spielfeld{"~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~"};                                                                         ^
schiffe3.java:96: error: not a statement                                               
String[] Spielfeld{"~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~"};                                                                          ^ 
schiffe3.java:96: error: ';' expected                                                  
String[] Spielfeld{"~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~, "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~"};                                                                             
schiffe3.java:97: error: ';' expected                                                  
String[] Spielfelde{"~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~"};                                                                         
schiffe3.java:97: error: not a statement                                               
String[] Spielfelde{"~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~"};                                                                          
schiffe3.java:97: error: ';' expected                                                  
String[] Spielfelde{"~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~"};                                                                             
schiffe3.java:98: error: ';' expected                                                  
String[] Spielfeldek{"~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~"};                                                                         
schiffe3.java:98: error: not a statement                                               
String[] Spielfeldek{"~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~"};                                                                          
schiffe3.java:98: error: ';' expected                                                  
String[] Spielfeldek{"~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", ~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~"};                                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not initializing them properly. They must be initialized like:

```
String[] Spielfeld = {"~", "~", "~", "~", "~"}
```

or

```
Spielfeld = new String[]{"~", "~", "~", "~", "~"}
```

if you're replacing the array at a point not at the declaration. Obviously, your arrays would be longer, but that shouldn't be an issue at *this* point.

Comment: Please mark the checkmark next to my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter alternative

```
String[] spielfeld = 
"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~".split("");
```

What you have a array which is too big you get the error

```
Error: java: code to large
```

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/java-arrays-wat.html